# Jquery Mobile Cordova Page Change Speed

Tags: android, jquery, performance, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app written in Cordova 6 with the latest jquerymobile and jquery libraries running on Android. There is 3 tabs across the top, which load 3 different pages. I have used the single page architechture, so only have one html file with multiple data-role="page" within it.

I am not using page transitions, and have switched them off, and use the vclick everywhere.

The problem is that the displaying of the pages is delayed relative to the highlighting of the tab once it's clicked. E.g. once you click a new page tab, the tab is highlighted almost instantly, but the page loads about 500ms later. The pages don't contain a lot of data, just some small lists. Is there a way around this delay?

Comment: where have you tried this. emulator, real phone? do you get the same lag in a normal browser?

Comment: Using an octacore phone. Didn't use browser as it won't run in the browser.

Comment: If you have access to another android phone give it another test to see if same

Comment: It's the same on all phones.

Comment: Then enable debugging in cordova and plug a usb cable to your pc -- maybe you have erros in the console -- details here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Comment: Console is active in eclipse while running it. No errors.